# Return matching sql rows based on distance

Tags: mysql, sql, database, gis

Pretty simple actually, I just don't know how to do this.

I have a table:

```
table locations 
location_id     coordinates    name
-------------------------------------
```

When I receive the latitude and longitude from the device I store it inside of a variable in mysql of type POINT(Long, Lat).

I'm trying to get all of the rows in the Locations table that have a distance less than or equal to eight meters.

My query is as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM locations where st_distance_sphere(@userCoords, @pt1)  <= 8;
```

I know this query is wrong because `@pt1` is not associated with the column coordinates. How can I isolate the specific value in the coordinates column and return the list of rows that match?

the `st_distance_sphere()` function just calculates the distance between two coordinates and returns a number.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

all you need is to put the column instead of `@pt1` (assuming the column type is Point):

```
SELECT * 
FROM locations 
where st_distance_sphere(@userCoords, coordinates)  <= 8;
```

This will give you all rows which their coordinates are 8 or less from @userCoords

Comment: Savior. Thanks for helping a newb :D